# Array elements have null fields

Tags: java, arrays, null

I've this class:

```
public class MenuUpElement {

    Class<?> classe;
    String label;
    int viewId;

    public MenuUpElement(int viewId, String label, Class<?> classe) {
        viewId = this.viewId;
        classe = this.classe;
        label = this.label;
    }
}
```

Then I have a static class *StaticClass* with this declaration:

```
public static final MenuUpElement[] menuUpElements = new MenuUpElement[]{
    new MenuUpElement(12, "Main", MainActivity.class)
    , new MenuUpElement(13, "Second", SecondActivity.class)
    };
```

If I loop through *StaticClass.menuUpElements* in another class, I found two elements (correct) but all null (wrong):

```
menuUpElements[0].classe = null
menuUpElements[0].viewId= 0
menuUpElements[0].label= null

menuUpElements[1].classe = null
menuUpElements[1].viewId= 0
menuUpElements[1].label= null
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assignments in your constructor are backwards

```
public MenuUpElement(int viewId, String label, Class<?> classe) {
    viewId = this.viewId;
    classe = this.classe;
    label = this.label;
}
```

Consider

```
public MenuUpElement(int viewId, String label, Class<?> classe) {
    this.viewId = viewId;
    this.classe = classe;
    this.label  = label;
}
```

Comment: AH AH AH OH MY GOD DUMB DUMB DUMB!!! I did it tons of times :P Maybe, yesterday I was too tired ;)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `MenuUpElement` is wrong, you're setting the parameters with the values of the fields. It should be the other way around:

```
public MenuUpElement(int viewId, String label, Class<?> classe) {
    this.viewId = viewId;
    this.classe = classe;
    this.label = label;
}
```